# Why React native loads all my screens when I open the app (onAuthChange)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am building an application, where I have 4 screens set up. One for Login (LoginScreen.js), my main screen (AllatokScreen.js), AuthChanged screen and navigation screen. My navigation logic is the following:
App.js --> AuthNavigation.js --> If(I have user) --> navigation.js SignedIn/ --else--> navigation.js SignedOut

This way the app starts, there is no user, so it loads , then it finds user goes to , then my main screen, but why?

I tried to also cover up this whole thing with a loading "dog" icon, but it just never there. Where is ther error in my logic?

This is my Main screen.js:

```
//*all imports*

const window = Dimensions.get('window');

const AllatokScreen = ({navigation, route}) => {
  const [loading,setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [allatok, setAllat] = useState([])
  const [user, setUser] = useState(auth.currentUser);


  const loadAnimails = () => {
    setLoading(true);

    //Make query from database
    var userRoot = ref(db, "users/"+auth.currentUser.uid+"/allatok");
    let updatedValue = {};

    onValue(userRoot, (snapshot) => {
      var data = snapshot.val();
      var key;
      for (var line in data) {
          key = line;
          updatedValue = {"allatID":line, "allatFaj": data[key]['AllatFaj'],allatNev: data[key]['AllatNev']};
          if (!allatok.some(element=> JSON.stringify(element) === JSON.stringify(updatedValue))) {
            setAllat(allatok => [...allatok, updatedValue])
            }
      }
    });
  }

  
  useEffect(() => {
    loadAnimails();
    setLoading(false);
  },
  [])

  const AllatInfo = (props) => (
    <View style={{width:240, justifyContent:'space-evenly'}}>
      <Text style={styles.titleStyle}>{props.item.allatNev}</Text>
      <Text style={{fontWeight:'800'}}>Kor: 10</Text>
    </View>
  )

  const AllatKep = (props) => (
    <View>
      {props.item.allatFaj == 'kutya'? <Image style={styles.image} source={kutya}/>: null }
      {props.item.allatFaj == 'macska'? <Image style={styles.image} source={macska}/>: null }
      {props.item.allatFaj == 'nyul'? <Image style={styles.image} source={nyul}/>: null }
      {props.item.allatFaj == 'gekko'? <Fontisto name="picture" size={50}/>: null }
    </View>
  )

  const FAB = () => (
    <View style={{flex:1 ,alignItems:'center', flexDirection:'row', position:'absolute',
    top:(window.height)*0.78,
    zIndex:999}}>
      <View style={{flexDirection:'row',
                    justifyContent:'center',
                    width:'100%'}}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{
          marginTop:20,
          backgroundColor:'green',
          alignItems:'center',
          padding:13,
          borderRadius:30,
          width:(window.width)*0.15,
          position:'relative'
        }}
        onPress={() => {navigation.push('AllatokScreen_to_AddAllat')}}>
          <Icon name="plus" size={30} color='#ffffff'/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  )

  return (
    <>
    {loading ? <View style={styles.loading_position}>
        <LottieView
            style={{height:150}}
            source={loading_gif}
            autoPlay
            speed={1}
            />
        </View> : 
      <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'white'}}>
        {(() => {
          if (Object.keys(allatok).length === 0){
            return (
                  <Text style={{textAlign:"center", padding:20, fontSize: 20}}>Még nem adtál hozzá egyetlen állatot sem, a zöld gomb segítségével ezt meg tudod tenni {emoji.getUnicode("slightly_smiling_face")}</Text>
                  )
            }
          else {
            return (
              <FlatList data = {allatok} renderItem={({item}) => (
              <View>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.cardLook} onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('AllatokScreen_to_InsideAllat', item.allatID)}}>
                  <View style={styles.container}>
                      <AllatInfo item={item}/>
                      <AllatKep item={item}/>
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            )}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}/>
            )
        }
      })()}
        <FAB/>
      </View>
      }
    </>
  );
  }
export default AllatokScreen;


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    justifyContent:"space-between",
    flexDirection:"row",
    margin:20,
  },
  titleStyle:{
    fontSize:20,
    fontWeight:'bold',
  },
  image:{
    height:80,
    width:80,
    resizeMode:'contain',
    borderRadius:12
  },
  cardLook:{
    borderRadius: 50,
    borderWidth: 3,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    shadowOffset: { width: 5, height: 5 },
    shadowColor: '#333',
    shadowOpacity: 0.3,
    shadowRadius: 3,
    marginHorizontal: 4,
    marginVertical: 6,
    //Fix méretű kártyák, középen legyen
    height:120,
    alignItems:'center',
    justifyContent:'center',
  },
  loading_position: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
}

});
```

This is my App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import AuthNavigation from './AuthNavigation';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <AuthNavigation/>
      );
}
```

This is my navigation.js:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View  } from 'react-native';

//Load external modules
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';


//Load my stuff
import InsideAllat from './src/InsideAllat';
import Oltasok from './src/Oltasok';
import Kullancsok from './src/Kullancsok';
import AllatokScreen from './src/AllatokScreen';
import AddAllat from './src/AddAllat';
import LoginScreen from './src/LoginScreen';


//Itt hozzuk létre a Stack widgeteket
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export const SignedIn = () => (
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator InitialRouteName="App_to_AllatokScreen" screenOptions={
            {
            headerTintColor: 'white',
            headerStyle: {backgroundColor: 'green'}
            }
        }>
            <Stack.Screen name="App_to_AllatokScreen" component = {AllatokScreen} options={
            {
                title: 'E-Kisállatkönyv!',
                headerTitleAlign: 'center',
                headerTitleStyle: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                fontSize: 20,
                color: 'white'
                }
            }
            }/>
            <Stack.Screen name="AllatokScreen_to_InsideAllat" component = {InsideAllat} options={
            {
                title: 'Opciók',
                headerTitleAlign: 'center',
                headerTitleStyle: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                fontSize: 20,
                color: 'white'
                }
            }
            }/>
            <Stack.Screen name="AllatokScreen_to_AddAllat" component = {AddAllat} options={
            {
                title: 'Új állat hozzáadása!',
                headerTitleAlign: 'center',
                headerTitleStyle: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                fontSize: 20,
                color: 'white'
                }
            }
            }/>
            <Stack.Screen name="InsideAllat_to_Oltasok" component = {Oltasok} options={{
                title: 'Oltások',
                headerTitleAlign: 'center',
                headerTitleStyle: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                fontSize: 20,
                color: 'white'
                }
            }}/>

            <Stack.Screen name="Oltasok_to_Oltasok" component = {Oltasok}/>
            <Stack.Screen name="InsideAllat_to_Kullancsok" component = {Kullancsok} options={{
                title: 'Kullancsok',
                headerTitleAlign: 'center',
                headerTitleStyle: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                fontSize: 20,
                color: 'white'
                }
            }}/>
        </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
)

export const SignedOut = () => (
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator InitialRouteName="LoginScreen"   screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
            <Stack.Screen name="LoginScreen" component = {LoginScreen}/>
        </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
)
```

This is my AuthNavigation.js:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { SignedIn, SignedOut } from "./navigation";
import { auth } from "./shared/setup";
import {onAuthStateChanged} from 'firebase/auth';
import { View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
//LottieView
import LottieView from 'lottie-react-native';
import {loading_gif} from './assets';

const AuthNavigation  = () => {
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
    const [loading,setLoading] = useState(true);

    const userHandler = user => user ? setCurrentUser(user) : setCurrentUser(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => {userHandler = userHandler(user)});
        
        setLoading(false);
    },[])

    return(
        <>
        {loading 
        ? 
            <View style={styles.loading_position}>
                <LottieView style={{height:150}} source={loading_gif} autoPlay speed={1}/>
            </View> 
        : 
            <>{currentUser ? <SignedIn/> : <SignedOut/>}</>
        }       
        </>
    );
}

export default AuthNavigation;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    loading_position: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    }

  });
```

[image]

Comment: Just to understand what you are saying, your app is navigating to LoginScreen for a second, then redirects to MainScreen, but you want it to directly navigate to MainScreen when a user is present?

Comment: Yes, and I tried to fill that time in AuthNavigation.js with a loading icon, but it is still rendering the login screen...